# subsequential limits of $\sin(n\pi x)$ when $x$ rational and $x$ irrational

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. Prove the sequence $a_n= \sin(n\pi x)$, $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$ has finitely many subsequential limits (accumulation points) iff $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and every number in $[-1,1]$ is an accumulation point, if $x$ is irrational.

I need **hints** on this problem. Not sure where to start. Please, **don't solve it for me**, just some hints to help me figure out on my own. Thanks :)

(I have only covered the first 3 chapters of baby rudin in my class)

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, (the case where $x \in \mathbb Q$ ) take $x= \frac 3 7$ and calculate $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots$. You will see a pattern. For example $\sin \left( \frac{21 \pi}{7} \right) = 0$. Try to generalize for any rational $x$.

On the other hand, when $x \in \mathbb Q^c$, observe that $y:= \pi x$ is also irrational, and now you will have to show that $\{ \sin (ny) : n \in \mathbb N \}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. This denseness somehow implies that every number in $[-1,1]$ is an accumulation point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $[y]$ be the largest integer not exceeding the real number $y$. (This is an older,pre-computer, notation for "floor (y)". ) For rational $x=a/b$ with integer $a$ and positive integer $b$ , how many different values can $[n x]$ have for integer $n$ ? For irrational $x$ , prove that $\{[n x] : n\in Z\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$.Remark:The newer notation for $[x]$ takes 14 keystrokes in LaTeX including one mandatory space.The old one takes 3.And I'm an awful typist.